# Encode viewmodel properties to JavaScript in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a simple ViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool ShowWelcomeMsg { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view I need this property in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ShowWelcomeMsg = @Model.ShowWelcomeMsg;
</script>
```

But that's not correct because it outputs `False` instead of `false` but anyway, the question is more generic because I want to know the solution for int, string, etc as well:

*What is the correct way to encode a viewmodel property to use it in JavaScript (in Razor)?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ShowWelcomeMsg = @Html.Raw(Model.ShowWelcomeMsg);
</script>
```

You should serialize first your data. Instead of passing a boolean, you should pass a string with json notation:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string ShowWelcomeMsg { get; set; }
}
```

In order to serialize to json you should do:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var vm = new IndexViewModel
    {
         ShowWelcomeMsg = serializer.Serialize(true)
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

This way you can even serialize a whole C# Object and use it as any other object in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a good approach, I think I will build a custom html helper which will encode it to json. I absolutely don't want to do that in the controller or the viewmodel. I'm just wondering why this is not build-in or I'm unable to find it...

Comment: Sure! you don't want that code neither in your controller nor viewmodel, a html helper sounds like a clean approach, glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

You could just handle the conversion yourself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ShowWelcomeMsg = @(Model.ShowWelcomeMsg ? "true" : "false");
    var WelcomeMsg = "@Model.WelcomeMsg.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")";
</script>
```

Comment: That would work for my simple example but what about a string with linebreak?